# 3D cube appears stretched when rendered

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have a basic opengl project that draws a 3D cube to the screen. My resolution is 1600 x 900. No matter how far or close the camera is to the cube, the cube always appears stretched horizontally to look like a triangle. I've loaded the same cube into a java project and it draws perfectly. But with the same code in C++, I get a stretched effect. Any suggestions as to what may be causing this?

```
GLvoid RenderSettings::init()
{
    const GLfloat FOV = 60.0F; 
    const GLfloat ASPECT_RATIO = getScreenWidth() / getScreenHeight();
    const GLfloat NEAREST_VIEW = 1.0F;
    const GLfloat FARTHEST_VIEW = 1000.0F;

    glViewport(0, 0, getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(FOV, ASPECT_RATIO, NEAREST_VIEW, FARTHEST_VIEW);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

}
```

Comment: Do you have the same window height, width and FOV in both projects?

Comment: What happens if you adjust the FOV? Maybe 30 instead of 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
const GLfloat ASPECT_RATIO = getScreenWidth() / getScreenHeight();
```

has your problem. I presume `getScreenWidth` and `getScreenHeight` return integers. In C/C++ when dividing integers this happens as integer operation, which means the result will be rounded down (always) to the next smaller integer. The type you assign the result to doesn't matter. C/C++ look at the types of L-values and R-values independently. You can fix it by typecasting one side of the division to a float (usually you just cast both), i.e.

```
GLfloat const ASPECT_RATIO = (float)getScreenWidth() / (float)getScreenHeight();
```

---

Also note that the `const` qualifier is left associative, i.e. it acts on what's left of it. Only if it's the *very first* token in a variable definition statement it acts toward the right. But many language purists (including me) consider this to look ugly. Also writing const after the type caters more to the natural language.

Comment: So you prefer `char* const s = 'a';` over `const char* s = 'a';`? `const` qualifiers have always confused me when they're to the right of a statement, not really sure why..

Comment: He prefers `int const foo = 1` over `const int foo = 1`. Nice catch @datenwolf

Comment: @user1520427: `char const *` (which means pointer to a immutable memory of char(s)) is something different as `char * const` (immutable pointer to a memory of mutable char(s)). And there's also `char const * const` (immutable pointer to immutable memory of char(s)).